# Unable to pass maven property to ant run plugin

Tags: java, maven, ant, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have a problem passing a custom maven property (version)
to an script executed by maven using the `maven-antrun-plugin.`

I have already read [Maven antrun: pass maven properties to ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128706/maven-antrun-pass-maven-properties-to-ant) but this didn't solve the problem.

There is one difference between my problem and the one given within the mentioned SO question.

In my case the `maven-antrun-plugin` is executed as a child of an parent project, where the property is defined as a global property for all modules.

The maven-antrun-plugin is one module of the project.

Parent pom snippet looks like this:

```
<project ...> 
  <!-- Parent -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
     <my.project.version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</my.project.version>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
     <java.version>1.7</java.version>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
```

ant run pom looks like this. The property is named `target.version`

```
<project>
      <!-- Module -->
 <parent>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent> 

 <build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>ant-magic</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <tasks>
                        <property name="compile_classpath" 
                                  refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                        <property name="outputDir"
                                  value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
                        <property name="sourceDir"
                                  value="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"/>
                        <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>

                        <property name="target-version" refid="${my.project.version}"/>
                        <echo message="Passed target version to ant build script: ${target-version}"/>      

                        <ant antfile="${basedir}/src/main/ant/create-dist.xml"
                             target="deploy-ea"/>
                      </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The following maven build error occurs during the excution of the build of  the child module which contains the antrun-maven-plugin.

```
`An Ant BuildException has occured: Reference 0.0.3-SNAPSHOT` not found
```

which is interesting because this is the value of the maven property.

I also tried just to use the simple property name as argument for the

```
refid attribute
```

In my case

```
<property name="target-version" refid="my.project.version"/>
```

Which leads to the following error:

```
   An Ant BuildException has occured: Reference my.project.version not found
```

The ant script uses the property as follows

```
<property name="myproject-jar" value="mymodulename-${target-version}.jar"/>
```

Do I have a mistake within my configuration or is the problem that the property is defined within the parent pom. And therefor maybe a maven lifecycle issue?

Comment: First your pom snippet does not look like it inherits from a parent which is the case if you are within the module of a larger multi module build...Furthermore the question is why are you using maven-antrun-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Firstly, because i wanted to show just the relevent parts of the problem, in this case the pom snippets. Secondly i use the ant plugin because i need to build native C++, JNI, stuff and this way it seems for me to be the most pragmatic way. Maybe you can offer me a nice solution to build a c++ project.using maven, concerning the appropriate java client leveraging its functionallity.

Comment: I can recommend to take a look at https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin ...

Comment: yes ok thx. I know this plugin. It's the next step, a lot of configuration stuff. But can you give me a solution for my given problem and not any alternatives. Because the problem is really easy to solve right now by changing just the property manually. I asked the question because it seemed to me that it is pretty strange behaviour. Because concerning the references SO question there should be no problem.

Comment: Are Ant properties allowed to contain hyphens?

Comment: I have my doubts...I would suggest to use `target.version` instead of `target-version`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the wrong attibute name `refid` for the `property`-Tag. Changing the attribute to `value` solved the problem. Additionally i replaced the `tasks` tag to `target` because it is marked as deprecated. But this had no influence to the given problem.

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ant-magic</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <property name="compile_classpath" 
                                          refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                                <property name="outputDir"
                                          value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
                                <property name="sourceDir"
                                          value="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"/>
                                <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>

                                <property name="target-version" value="${my.project.version}"/> <!-- PROBLEM refid should be value-->
                                <echo message="Passed target version to ant build script: ${target-version}"/>      

                                <ant antfile="${basedir}/src/main/ant/create-dist.xml"
                                     target="deploy-ea"/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```